# Parse a date return null

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, momentjs

I'm trying to parse a date, in particular this:

> Mer Nov 11 2015 00:00:00

into this:

> Mer Nov 11 2015 09:00:00

so I've made this code:

```
var workDateStart = Date.parseExact(calendarDateStart.toString('dd/MM/yyyy') + ' '+ workingPlan[selDayName].start,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
```

The problem's that this code return a `null` value.

**MORE DETAILS VARIABLE VALORIZATION**

```
workingPlan[selDayName].start => 09:00

calendarDateStart => Mer Nov 11 2015 00:00:00
```

1. The workingPlan varialble contains all working plan days of my
   providers, I get the specific day (work start) through passing
   selDayName as index.
2. calendarDateStart contains the actual date of the Calendar.

Comment: `Date.parseExact` - what API is that??  It's not moment.js, nor the JavaScript built-in `Date` object.  Perhaps you meant to tag [tag:datejs] instead of [tag:momentjs] ?

Comment: it's a method of Javascript Date, anyway I can see any solution if you propose one.

Comment: Nope, sorry - it's not.  You can review the `Date` object's API [on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).  I think you're using date.js, but you didn't tag your question that way.  You did tag moment.js, but nothing in your question uses that.  BTW - `toString` doesn't take parameters either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit clumsy, but if you want to do this with pure JavaScript (no libraries) the following should work.

```
var workDateStart = new Date(calendarDateStart.toDateString() + ' ' + workingPlan[selDayName].start);
```

This assumes `calendarDateStart` and `workDateStart` are both `Date` objects (not strings), and that `workingPlan[selDayName].start` is indeed a string in the format you provided.

As an isolated example:

```
var d = new Date();                            // some date object
var timeString = '09:00';                      // some time-only string
var s = d.toDateString() + ' ' + timeString;   // combined
var result = new Date(s);                      // parsed back to a Date object
```

If you want to do this using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), it's like this:

```
var m = moment();                              // some moment object
var timeString = '09:00';                      // some time-only string
var s = m.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' ' + timeString;   // combined
var result = moment(s, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');    // parsed back to a moment object
```

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2707) to add a more sensible function to moment's API in the future.

Comment: Can you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668207/momentjs-return-wrong-date-hour/33673735?noredirect=1#comment55122746_33673735 please